# Some questions about WTSInfoExLevel

Tags: visual-c++, wtsapi32

I did not get much help from MSDN so posting question on the expert forum:

1. What is the difference between `WTSInfoExLevel1.IncomingCompressedBytes`  and `WTSInfoExLevel1.IncomingBytes`

Is `WTSInfoExLevel1.IncomingCompressedBytes` the size of the data after (`WTSInfoExLevel1.IncomingBytes`)  compression OR it is the size of data which was sent compressed.

2. Same question about the `WTSInfoExLevel1.OutgoingCompressedBytes` and `WTSInfoExLevel1.OutgoingBytes`

Comment: Compression is used to keep the data transfer as small as possible.  That doesn't always pan out well, it depends on the kind of data that gets transferred.  So these members are useful to diagnose a slow remote connection issue.

Comment: So I assume that Total Bytes Sent on the network is CompressedBytes + Bytes.

Comment: No, it is bytes at server => compression => network => decompression => bytes at client.  The network transfers CompressedBytes.